# Explicit context lost in collection.fetch()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I try to pass a view object as context to the fetch callback:

```
var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/tree/list.php'
});
var list = new List();

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    test: 'ok',
    initialize: function() {
        list.fetch({
            context: this
        })
        .done(function(){
            alert(this.test);
        });
    }
});

var view = new View();
```

And that works fine and alerts 'ok', but that:

```
var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/tree/list.php'
});
var list = new List();

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    test: 'ok',
    initialize: function() {
        list.fetch({
            context: this,
            success: function(){
                alert(this.test);
            }
        });
    }
});

var view = new View();
```

alerts nothing.

In the second case, why is the context lost, although I **explicitly** pass  a `context` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

This is because your in your first example you are attaching your callback to the jqXHR returned by Collection.fetch which respects the context parameter passed through to it by Backbone.ajax.

Your second example passes a success callback to the Collection, which in turn is invoked by Backbone, not jQuery. Hence the context parameter is disregarded. A look at the Backbone source code confirms this:

```
fetch: function(options) {
      options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
      if (options.parse === void 0) options.parse = true;
      var success = options.success;
      var collection = this;
      options.success = function(resp) {
        var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
        collection[method](resp, options);
        if (success) success(collection, resp, options);
        collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
      };
      wrapError(this, options);
      return this.sync('read', this, options);
    },
```

In backbone, it is recommended that you use events and the `listenTo` method provided by Backbone.View. This method ensures that the context is correct when the event handler is called and that the listener is removed whenever the view is removed with backbone.View.remove():

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  test: 'ok',
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection = new Backbone.Collection({url:'/endpoint');
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.onSync);
  },
  onSync: function(){
    alert(this.test); // Works
  }
})
```

Comment: Now everything is clear! I had to look deeper. Do you think this is normal behavior or mistaken?

Comment: @brizz Depends on your point of view, you can always declare a bound callback, `success: _.bind(function() {}, this)`

Comment: The difference lies in the success handler you define and from where that is called. The done handler is part of jQuery, whereas the success handler is part of Backbone. Backbone lets you pass the context property to the jQuery.ajax call and in your first example, you also attatch a done handler to the jQuery HXR object returned by Collection.fetch. This is what makes it work. In the second example, the context property is still passed to jQuery.ajax, but Backbone's success hook does not use it as Backbone has it's own mechanism for maintaining context.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely that it happens because you loose your context while calling success function.  The context of success is window element.  If you want to pass this to success create var self = this in your initialize function and than do alert(self.test)

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    test: 'ok',
    initialize: function() {
    var self = this;

        list.fetch({

            success: function(){
                alert(self.test);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As an alternative you could also do:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    test: 'ok',
    initialize: function() {
        list.fetch({
            context: this,
            success: function(collection,response,options){
                alert(options.context.test);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The first example - it is obvious solution and its ok. But why in my example contect passed explicitly by context parameter. And why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    test: 'ok',

    initialize: function() {
        var that = this;

        list.fetch({
            // context: this,
            success: function(){
                alert(that.test);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The issue is the content in which `this` is being used.

In your second example, `this` looks like it's pointing to the object literal being passed to `list.fetch()` (the object containing the `context` and `success` properties), which doesn't have a property called test, thus it's alerting `undefined`.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the context property for other purposes you could use `alert(this.context.test)` I think.

Comment: actually I dont think you can do that. this is pointing to the window object. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wb45v/6/ . I'm doing on error instead of success, because obviously i dont get response from the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3704713/mikewu is write. And i stell not understand why 'context' option works in first case and does not in second. For example, if i use $.ajax for the same situation it works as expected

Comment: @MikeWu Yeah, you're right - you can access test through `options.context.test`, i.e. `console.log(options.context.test); //ok`